# mySQL update table add string to column

Tags: mysql, string, addition

I have a table in mySQL and want to update a specific column holding a directory.
The directory structure should be extended and the corresponding columns should be updated with a subdirectory. There are many rows to update so I look for a convenient script to do.

Example:

column c1 holds directory

```
/startpoint/dir_a/
/startpoint/dir_a/subdir_1/
/startpoint/dir_a/subdir_1/subsubdir_1/
/startpoint/dir_a/subdir_1/subsubdir_2/
/startpoint/dir_a/subdir_1/subsubdir_3/
/startpoint/dir_a/subdir_2/
/startpoint/dir_a/subdir_3/
```

So I need to move directories followed from startpoint to startpoint/system.

This should be in after script:

```
/startpoint/system/dir_a/
/startpoint/system/dir_a/subdir_1/
/startpoint/system/dir_a/subdir_1/subsubdir_1/
/startpoint/system/dir_a/subdir_1/subsubdir_2/
/startpoint/system/dir_a/subdir_1/subsubdir_3/
/startpoint/system/dir_a/subdir_2/
/startpoint/system/dir_a/subdir_3/
```

My (maybe silly) update didn't work as expected:

```
update table1 set dir=/startpoint/system/||substr(dir,12) where dir like '/startpoint/dir_a/%'
```

So any idea from expert to do this with a more specific sql update ?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct your UPDATE query... quote should be around the value of `dir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
UPDATE table SET dir = REPLACE(dir,'/startpoint/dir_a/','/startpoint/system/dir_a/'
WHERE dir LIKE '/startpoint/dir_a/%'
```

but be careful because it will replace all occurrences of '/startpoint/dir_a/' - if your path is something like '/startpoint/dir_a/random_dir/startpoint/dir_a/' it will mess it up.

Comment: Thanks ! Great and works really perfect. So as I define directory from startpoint there will be no miss with double named directories as subdirectories.